# Task classpath in ant : Java

Tags: java, ant, classpath, task

I've an error when I execute this in my ant and I don't understand why ant can't recognize the task classpath :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="task">

<target name="task">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="." />
    </classpath>
</target>

</project>
```

I have the error message :

```
task:

BUILD FAILED
C:\way\build.xml:6: Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Does someone know where the error comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `classpath` task in Ant (even though some tasks ***do*** allow you to specify a classpath. You ***can*** test out a basic Ant build using the `path` task, as an alternative:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project default="task">

<target name="task">
    <path id  = "class.dirs.path">
        <dirset dir  = "${build}" includes = "class.dir.list" />
    </path>
</target>
</project>
```